# Linker error compiling c-source using wininet with Mingw-w64

Tags: mingw-w64

I have a problem compiling c-source on windows. I use functions of wininet and got a linker error.
I use this version g++.exe (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>


int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    InternetOpen("WebReader", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0 ); 
    return 0;
}
```

the compile statement wirh error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe" -lwininet -g test.c -o test.exe
C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfXocKI.o: In function `main':
D:\source\mingw\ShellHost/test.c:9: undefined reference to `_imp__InternetOpenA@20'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LNK2019: Error. unresolved external symbol in C++ program using InternetOpen InternetReadFIle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3956252/lnk2019-error-unresolved-external-symbol-in-c-program-using-internetopen-int)

Answer (score 0):

You should link with `Wininet.lib` as `InternetOpenA` [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena) (see Requirements part).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was posted almost two years ago, but I wanted to expand on nevilad's answer to help someone in the future:

As nevilad said, adding the Wininet library as an additional dependency *should* fix this issue.

**In Visual Studios IDE... Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > add "Wininet.lib" to the list**